# Safari and ETag/If-None-Match Headers?

Tags: ios, http, caching, safari

From server I am returning the following headers,

```
Cache-Control:private
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:448
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 19 Jun 2013 09:27:46 GMT
ETag:00amyWGct0y_ze4lIsj2Mw
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

On nextrequests, Chrome will successfully send If-None-Match header but Safari not. Is Etag/If-None-Match supported by Safari? Anyone able to work ETag validation with Safari?